# React rendering variable with html characters escaped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am learning React and have run into the following situation:

I have a string variable that I am passing as a prop to different components to be rendered by JSX.

When the component and its sub-components are rendered, the string does not render html special characters, instead rendering the character code as text.

How can I get the variable to render as html?

Here is the code for a component that works completely, except that the `tempUnitString` variable renders as `&deg; K`, while the `<th>` below renders its units as ° K.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Chart from '../components/chart';
import GoogleMap from '../components/google_map'

class WeatherList extends Component {
  renderWeather(cityData, tempUnits){
    const name = cityData.city.name;
    const id = cityData.city.id;
    const humidity = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.humidity);
    const pressure = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.pressure);
    const { lon, lat } = cityData.city.coord;
    let temp = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp);
    if (tempUnits === "K"){
        temp = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp);
    } else if (tempUnits === "F"){
        temp = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp * 9/5 - 459.67);
    } else {
        temp = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp - 273.15);
    }
    let tempUnitString = "&deg; " + tempUnits;

    return (
      <tr key={ id }>
        <td><GoogleMap lat={ lat } lon={ lon } /></td>
        <td>
          <Chart color="red" data={ temp } units={ tempUnitString } />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Chart color="green" data={ pressure } units=" hPa" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Chart color="orange" data={ humidity } units="%" />
        </td>
      </tr>);
  }
  render() {
    const tempUnits = this.props.preferences.length > 0 ? this.props.preferences[0].tempUnits : "K";

    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Temperature (&deg; { tempUnits })</th>
            <th>Pressure (hPa)</th>
            <th>Humidity (%)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          { this.props.weather.map( item => this.renderWeather(item,tempUnits) ) }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }


}

function mapStateToProps({ weather, preferences }){// { weather } is shorthand for passing state and { weather:state.weather } below
  return { weather, preferences }; // === { weather:weather }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

**UPDATE**

Using the documentation passed to me by @James Ganong I set up a boolean prop on the subcomponent `isTemp` and based on that created a JSX variable.

The subcomponent (minus includes and func definitions) looks like this:

```
export default (props) => {
  let tempDeg = '';
  if (props.isTemp){
    tempDeg = <span>&deg;</span>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Sparklines height={ 120 } width={ 100 } data={ props.data }>
        <SparklinesLine color={ props.color } />
        <SparklinesReferenceLine type="avg" />
      </Sparklines>
      <div>{ average(props.data)} { tempDeg }{ props.units }</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The call to it looks like this:

`<Chart color="red" data={ temp } units={ tempUnits } isTemp={ true } />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React actually has a page that addresses this and some other potential solutions (using unicode characters, saving the file as utf8, using dangerouslySetInnerHtml): [jsx-gotchas](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html)

---

Another option is to create a simple, reusable Temp component that has types you pass it:

```js
const TEMP_C = 'C';
const TEMP_K = 'K';

const Temp = ({ children, unit }) => <span>{children}&deg;{unit}</span>;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Temperature 1: <Temp unit={TEMP_K}>25</Temp></p>
    <p>Temperature 2: <Temp unit={TEMP_C}>25</Temp></p>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. I marked it as the solution because you found documentation that I couldn't. haha. Ultimately, I need to customize this approach and use some conditional logic because I am running the temperature through a generic component that creates sparklines for temperature and other datasets.

I'll add my final solution as an additional solution below.

Comment: I wound up just updating the question with the solution.

Comment: Cheers - two things: 1. if you need to pass a prop as true (like `isTemp={true}`) you actually don't need the `={true}` part, just by setting `isTemp` as an attribute (without the equals) it evals to true. 2. You could combine the if statement into the jsx instead of needing to use the `tempDeg` variable. ie replace `{ tempDeg }` with `{props.isTemp && (<span>&deg;</span>)}`

Comment: Cheers to that as well!

Answer (score 0):

Without string concatenation html symbols works as usual. For some reason, when you concatenate a symbol with a string, then the symbol isn't decoded and it's rended as characters.

You can workaround it as in the example below or use a plugin ([html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities) for instance).

```js
const App = () => <Child deg="&deg;" temp={25} />;
const Child = ({deg, temp}) => <div>{temp} {deg}</div>;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Jordan,

The problem is that I want to pass the concatenated string into a separate component as a param. I would rather not have to put clunky conditional logic into the subcomponent, or create separate components just to handle this one case.

Comment: I checked out your approach, and the problem appears to be with the way that the string is being passed to the subcomponent

Comment: Perhaps a conversion from string variable to props property changes rendering behavior?

Comment: Here is described what's happening: http://reactjs.cn/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html. Thanks to James' answer.